# initializing "breuk *__strong" with an expression of incompatible type float

Tags: ios, objective-c

I checked several of the suggested links but did not find the answer. I want to pass twoo float values to the initalization of an object breuk. The object has an initalisationmethod initwithTeller: (float) mijnTeller andNoemer: (float) mijnNoemer. The method also returns a float quotient.

First of all I'm getting an error as in initalizing __strong with an expression of incompatible type float. It is given at the initialization of the object breuk in the method berekenQuotient.

I was also wondering if it's necessary to declare the properties mijnTeller and mijnNoemer in breuk.h as they are being passed down via berekenQuotient. tx !

Code:

viewcontroller.h:

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import "breuk.h"

   @interface ViewController : UIViewController
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tellerVeld1;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *noemerVeld1;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *quotientVeld;


   - (IBAction)berekenQuotient:(id)sender;
   @end
```

viewcontroller.M

```
   #import "ViewController.h"

   @interface ViewController ()

   @end

   @implementation ViewController
   @synthesize tellerVeld1;
   @synthesize noemerVeld1;
   @synthesize quotientVeld;


  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
     [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

  - (IBAction)berekenQuotient:(id)sender {
    float teller = [tellerVeld1.text floatValue];
    float noemer = [noemerVeld1.text floatValue];
    breuk *breuk1 = [[breuk alloc]initWithTeller:teller andNoemer:noemer];


    //float quotient = [tellerVeld1.text floatValue]/[noemerVeld1.text floatValue];
    //quotientVeld.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%.2f", quotient];

   }
   @end
```

breuk.h

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

  @interface breuk : NSObject
  @property float mijnTeller;
  @property float mijnNoemer;
  @property float quotient;



  - (float) initWithTeller: (float) mijnTeller andNoemer:(float) mijnNoemer;
   @end
```

breuk.m

```
   #import "breuk.h"

   @implementation breuk
   @synthesize mijnTeller;
   @synthesize mijnNoemer;
   @synthesize quotient;


   - (float)initWithTeller:(float)mijnTeller andNoemer:(float)mijnNoemer{
      return quotient = mijnTeller/mijnNoemer;

 }

 @end
```

Comment: `init` methods return `id`, and nothing else.  The naming is very important.

Comment: Yeah, there are likely other bugs, but your immediate problem is that `init` is mis-declared and mis-implemented.  `init` *must* return an instance of the object, and it *must* invoke the `super` version of `init` (or another `this` version) to obtain the instance.

Comment: (Based on your comments below I'd suggest you find a reference for "object-oriented programming" and study it.)

Answer (score 1):

All `init` methods should return an instance of its own class, what you want is just a class methods that does the calculation. Also all classes should start with a capital:

Breuk.h

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

  @interface Breuk : NSObject
  @property float mijnTeller;
  @property float mijnNoemer;
  @property (readonly) float quotient;

  - (instancetype) initWithTeller: (float) mijnTeller andNoemer:(float) mijnNoemer;
  @end
```

Breuk.m

```
  #import "Breuk.h"

   @implementation breuk

   @synthesize mijnTeller;
   @synthesize mijnNoemer;
   @synthesize quotient;

 - (id)initWithTeller:(float)mijnTeller andNoemer:(float)mijnNoemer{
     self = [super init];
     if (self) {
       self.mijnTeller = mijnTeller;
       self.mijnNoemer = mijnNoemer;
     }

     return self;
 }

 - (float) quotient {
     return mijnTeller/mijnNoemer;
 }

 @end
```

Or just with a class methods

Breuk.h

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

  @interface Breuk : NSObject

  + (float) quotientWithTeller:(float)teller andNoemer:(float)noemer;
   @end
```

Breuk.m

```
  #import "Breuk.h"

  @implementation breuk
  + (float) quotientWithTeller:(float)teller andNoemer:(float)noemer;
     return teller/noemer;
  }

  @end
```

With the class methods you do not need an instance of the `Breuk` class, just call it on the class:

```
 float quotient = [Breuk quotientWithTeller:teller andNoemer:noemer];
```

Comment: rcKoenes, I thank you for your answer. I learned a lot. I guess the class methods are used if you don't want to access the teller or noemer afterwards? The object info is lost?

Comment: @user2895954 class methods are used so you don not need an instance of the calls. It will not keep track of anything nor do you need to create an instance of the `Breuk` class.

Answer (score 1):

Your `init` method doesn't do it's job.  Try this:

```
@interface Breuk : NSObject {
    float _mijnTeller;
    float _mijnNoemer;
}
@property float mijnTeller;
@property float mijnNoemer;

- (id)initWithTeller:(float)mijnTeller
           andNoemer:(float)mijnNoemer;
- (float)quotient;
@end

@implementation Breuk 
@synthesize mijnTeller = _mijnTeller;
@synthesize mijnNoemer = _mijnNoemer;

- (id)initWithTeller:(float)mijnTeller
           andNoemer:(float)mijnNoemer {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _mijnTeller = mijnTeller;
        _mijnNoemer = mijnNoemer;
    }
    return self;
}

- (float)quotient {
    return mijnTeller / mijnNoemer;
}

@end
```

Comment: trojan, First of all I 'd like to thank you for your answer. I don't get why you're introducing the local variables inside the interface { }?

Comment: @user2895954 You don't strictly need to, as recent versions of `clang` do this for you when you use `@synthesize`, however I like to see what instance variables I have defined as it paints a picture of the class for me months down the line.  I think this new *time saving feature* will actually cost time and confusion in the future.

Comment: hmm new code worked when xcode was closed. otherwise it paused at self =[super init]

Comment: @user2895954 You'll need to start a new question, and post the code.  I cannot answer your question with no clues.

Comment: works :) now what was problem. Xcode had placed automatic breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error **initalizing __strong with an expression of incompatible type float** because `initWithTeller:andNoemer:` returns a float, but you are assigning it to `breuk1` which has the type `breuk`. By default, local variables like `breuk1` are **strong** references, that's where the __strong part of the error comes in.

You don't **have** to declare the properties `mijnTeller` and `mijnNoemer` in breuk.h.  You only need to do that if you are going to store those values and then use them again later.

I also see no need for you to try to create a `breuk` object in the first place, you could just use a class method to perform that calculation.

Comment: Jonathan, I thank you for your answer. I learned a lot. The reason I'm introducing an object is because I will create several breuk objects :)